# Make checked checkboxes stay checked after coming back to the page

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, checkbox

I have a page of items which are loaded by angularjs with `$http.get`.

On that same page, there are checkboxes of categories. For example, if user presses the checkbox `men`, angular fetches the items belonging to the `men` category without reloading the page.

Also, a user can click on some item and he will get to the detail page for that item.

The problem is that, when a user checks a category checkbox, chooses some item, gets to the detail page and presses the `back` button in the browser, all checkboxes are unchecked and he will see all the items, not the ones he filtered out a while ago.

How can I 'remember' what checkboxes he checked?

Comment: you can use cookies.

Comment: Or better, use local storage to save their state

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you currently store the category checkbox state in your controller, which is why when the user goes to the item details and then returns to the list of items the state is lost, since the controller is reloaded. In order to "remember" which checkboxes where checked you will need to create a service in which you will store the state of your checkboxes. Every time the user visits the item list page the controller will read the last state from the service and initialise the checkboxes accordingly. If the user then selects / deselects one or more checkboxes the controller will update the service in order for the new state to be stored.